# Prove that if $A_k \to A\,\, \left(A_k,\,\,A >0\right)$ then $\sqrt[n]{A_k} \to \sqrt[n]{A}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to prove the following result.
If
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}A_k = A\,\,\,\,\,\, \left(A_k,\,\,A >0\right) $$
then
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{A_k} = \sqrt[n]{A}$$
I am interested in using the hints given in the book I am reading, but I don't know how to continue, so please help me along the following lines. Use the identity
$$ x^n -x_0 ^n = \left(x-x_0\right)\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}x_0+\ldots+x_0^{n-1}\right)$$
with $x=\sqrt[n]{A_k}$ and $x_0 = \sqrt[n]{A}$.

By replacing $x$ and $x_0$ we have
$$ \left(\sqrt[n]{A_k}\right)^n - \left(\sqrt[n]{A}\right)^n = A_{k}-A$$
so
$$ A_{k}-A=
\left(\sqrt[n]{A_k} - \sqrt[n]{A}\right)
\left(\left(\sqrt[n]{A_k}\right)^{n-1}+
\left(\sqrt[n]{A_k}\right)^{n-2}\left(\sqrt[n]{A}\right)+
\ldots+
\left(\sqrt[n]{A}\right)^{n-1}
\right)
$$
Then notice that all the terms in the sum are positive.....How to proceed?

Comment: I would use the definition of a limit and try using the same epsilon as in A_k.

Comment: This just comes from the fact that the function $x \mapsto \sqrt[n]{x}$ is continuous.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe This all depends on whether the exercise appears before or after this theorem in the book.

Comment: Assume you don't know that the n-th square root is continuos and want to show the result using the suggestions given by the book.

Comment: Contraposition: If the nth root even diverges, A_k diverges more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have come up with a solution.
We have
$$ \vert\sqrt[n]{A_k} - \sqrt[n]{A} \vert=
\frac{
\vert A_k-A \vert}{\left(\sqrt[n]{A_k}\right)^{n-1}+
\left(\sqrt[n]{A_k}\right)^{n-2}\sqrt[n]{A}+
\ldots+
\left(\sqrt[n]{A}\right)^{n-1}
}
<
\frac{\vert A_k-A \vert}{\left(\sqrt[n]{A}\right)^{n-1}}$$
Then

$\vert\sqrt[n]{A_k} - \sqrt[n]{A} \vert \to 0 $

given that $ \vert A_k-A \vert \to 0$

Comment: You don't need $A_k > A$ to prove the inequality. The important fact is that all the terms in the denominator are positive, so removing some of them will leave you with something greater.